# 2-way ANOVA in Python statsmodels yields different Sum of Squares than SPSS

Tags: anova, python, spss, sums-of-squares, statsmodels

I am learning to use Python for my statistical analyses, and while figuring out how to perform a 2-way ANOVA with statsmodels I found that my Python code yielded slightly aberrant values. Comparing the outputs you can see that the SS_Factor_1 values, and the Adjusted R2 are different for Python vs SPSS/Graphpad. Is this because of a mistake in my code, or some other reason? Are these differences due to something inherent in each software and so small I should just ignore them?

**Python code:**

```
formula = 'dependent_variable ~ C(factor_1) * C(factor_2)'
model = ols(formula, data=df_freq_time).fit()
aov_table = anova_lm(model, typ=2)
aov_table
```

**Python output:**
[image: output]

Also R2 = 0.722, and adj R2 = 0.694

**SPSS 2-way ANOVA results:**
[image: SPSS output ANOVA table]

**Graphpad Prism 2-way ANOVA results:**
[image: Graphpad output ANOVA table]

Comment: Do you get the same numbers in python if you use type 3 ANOVA, `typ=3`? (The differences are small, but look too small for differences in definition and too large for purely numerical precision issues.)

Comment: I thought it was too big a difference to be a precision issue as well. Using typ=3 gives me this [output](https://i.imgur.com/vKq7543.png). It introduces an intercept and changes the sum of squares for all of the terms. I tried typ=1, and that just made the same output table as typ=2 but added a column for mean square values.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that SPSS and GraphPad are the same, but your code's results are off.  It's probably due to use of Type III sum-of-squares.  Other things known to affect differences in SS are unbalanced sample size and missing data.

You're actually doing this the wrong way.  You should be using a textbook which goes through a worked problem for a 2-way ANOVA with an interaction term and Type III SS, with intermediate calculations so you can find out where your code is making an error.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your answer, but to clarify the anova_lm() function is a built-in function of the statsmodels package. I did not code it. For some reason specifying type III sum of squares (by setting typ=3) results in even [stranger output](https://i.imgur.com/vKq7543.png), whereas the type II and III SS settings yield close to correct results.